# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar

```
package com.medikoe.connect.androidmedikoeconnect.utilities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class PushReminder {

    private Activity activity;

    public PushReminder(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void addReminder(long startTime) throws SecurityException {

        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();

        ContentValues calEvent = new ContentValues();
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1); // XXX pick)
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Add Shop Reminder");
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTime);
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, addMinutes(startTime));
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
        calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE);

        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, calEvent);

        int id = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Created Calendar Event " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, id);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);

        Uri uri2 = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Reminder have been saved succes fully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private long addMinutes(long time) {
        Date date = new Date(time + 5 * 60 * 1000);
        return date.getTime();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create event and reminder. The moment i try to save reminder i am getting this exception.

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel

It works on some phones and in some it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried using `getWritableDatabase`?

Comment: Your question in general is unclear, in fact you don't even ask a question. Please refresh about [ask] good questions, as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Hille the question is how to get rid of this exception? What is the cause and how to solve it. Is that what are you seeking?

Comment: Then please clarify that with an [edit]. You should write all the neccessary information down here and then maybe someone will help you for free after you put some effort into the question.

Comment: Were you able to get rid of this exception ??